# Lifting points of étale group scheme.

Tags: commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, group-schemes

Consider the following setting: let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian complete discrete valuation ring (with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$) and let $K$ be its field of fractions. Now take $L$ be the completion of an algebraic extension, even infinite, of $K$, and let $S$ be the integral closure of $R$ inside $L$. What I want to prove is that if I take an étale finite group scheme $G$, represented by the étale Hopf algebra $A$, I have a bijection of sets
\begin{equation}
G(S/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}S):=\text{Hom}_{\text{R-Alg}}(A,S/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}S)\simeq \text{Hom}_{\text{R-Alg}}(A,S/\mathfrak{m}^{i}S):=G(S/\mathfrak{m}^{i}S)
\end{equation}
given for every $i$ by the composition with the projection to the next quotient. I guess that the main ingredient to prove this could be Hensel Lemma, since $R$ is Henselian, but I really don't see the proof. Any hint will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is sometimes the definition of an étale morphism. You have a map $\phi: S/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}S \rightarrow S/\mathfrak{m}^{i}S$ whose kernel $I=\mathfrak{m}^i/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}$ satisfies $I^2=0$, and you're trying to show
$$ \phi_*: \mathrm{Hom}_{R-Alg}(A,S/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}S) \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}_{R-Alg}(A,S/\mathfrak{m}^{i}S)$$

is bijective. This is called being formally étale. An étale ring homomorphism can be defined as one that is formally étale and essentially of finite presentation. See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8451/definition-of-%C3%A9tale-for-rings), for example.

The point is that ring maps with kernels $I$ satisfying $I^2=0$ correspond to little deformations. An étale morphism is supposed to be an analogue of a map of complex analytic varieties that is a *local isomorphism*. One way to interpret that is if you are given a point in the domain of a local isomorphism, there is a bijection between a small neighbourhood of that point and its image. Algebraically formulated, this becomes a formally étale morphism,